# Office.context.document.url still empty after saving the file

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-addins, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

I'm developing an Office task pane add-in for Microsoft Project and I bumped into a serious limitation.

After creating a new project file, I load up the task pane app, which has a subfunction, that reads the **Office.context.document.url** property, which should have the full path to the file.

Obviously, at first, it's empty, because it's an unsaved project, but after I save the project, and fire the subfunction again, the url is still empty.

I suppose, the document object is not reloaded at any point during saving. How can I do that manually? If it's possible...

Here's the subfunction that returns the project path:

```
function getProjectPath() {
    var documenturl = Office.context.document.url;
    if (documenturl == null || documenturl == "") {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return documenturl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is about Project, who does not support this method, but to have dynamic access to the file url for Word, Excel and PPT, I recommend you to use the [getFilePropertiesAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfilepropertiesasync) method.

here is a sample on how to use it:

```js
function getFileUrl() {
    //Get the URL of the current file.
    Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync(function (asyncResult) {
        var fileUrl = asyncResult.value.url;
        if (fileUrl == "") {
            showMessage("The file hasn't been saved yet. Save the file and try again");
        }
        else {
            showMessage(fileUrl);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: just added to my answer that this is only supported in Word, Excel and PPT, unfortunately not in Project, who only has the static property, as of now.

Comment: Exactly. Tried to force that function on Project, before posting this question, but with no luck (obviously).
Any known ways,to re-initiate the Office.context or Office.context.document objects?

Comment: Any one know how can we achieve for MS Project pls

Comment: Is there a way to get an event, when user saves file under another name? @JuanBalmori

Comment: there is no such event.